# Flexbox height bigger than screen become invisible at the top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a problem with a overlay.

I want an overlay than can center the content on every screen size.
The problem with my method is that it works fine if the height of my content is smaller than the height of the screen but when the height of my content is bigger, it disappear and i can't access even with scroll :

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 101;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#content {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="content">
    <div>Some content 1</div>
    <div>Some content 2</div>
    <div>Some content 3</div>
    <div>Some content 4</div>
    <div>Some content 5</div>
    <div>Some content 6</div>
    <div>Some content 7</div>
    <div>Some content 8</div>
    <div>Some content 9</div>
    <div>Some content 10</div>
    <div>Some content 11</div>
    <div>Some content 12</div>
    <div>Some content 13</div>
    <div>Some content 14</div>
    <div>Some content 15</div>
    <div>Some content 16</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to see the top of the div at the top of the screen if the height is too big.
Any idea why it does this ? Or any other solution than can work in every screen ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase you have told the `#content` div of the `#overlay` div to be centered.

Apply `justify-content: flex-start;` to the `#overlay` so that the scrollable content can start at the top.

If you want to center that content at *less* that 100vh heights, then you will need javascript I would suggest to determine the height of the content vs. the height of the overlay.

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start; /* adjust here */
  z-index: 101;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#content {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="content">
    <div>Some content 1</div>
    <div>Some content 2</div>
    <div>Some content 3</div>
    <div>Some content 4</div>
    <div>Some content 5</div>
    <div>Some content 6</div>
    <div>Some content 7</div>
    <div>Some content 8</div>
    <div>Some content 9</div>
    <div>Some content 10</div>
    <div>Some content 11</div>
    <div>Some content 12</div>
    <div>Some content 13</div>
    <div>Some content 14</div>
    <div>Some content 15</div>
    <div>Some content 16</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>End content</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will do this. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `overflow:scroll;` for your `#content` div that will allow you to scroll and 
make all the entry visible.

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 101;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#content {
  overflow:scroll; 
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="content">
    <div>Some content 1</div>
    <div>Some content 2</div>
    <div>Some content 3</div>
    <div>Some content 4</div>
    <div>Some content 5</div>
    <div>Some content 6</div>
    <div>Some content 7</div>
    <div>Some content 8</div>
    <div>Some content 9</div>
    <div>Some content 10</div>
    <div>Some content 11</div>
    <div>Some content 12</div>
    <div>Some content 13</div>
    <div>Some content 14</div>
    <div>Some content 15</div>
    <div>Some content 16</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **overflow-x: hidden;**. For example

```
 



#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 101;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
#content {
  overflow:scroll; 
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```